# C# Substring return wrong value

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-framework-version

```
var newEncodedFiles = @"C:\Users\wande\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Spira\Spira\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\Translated\master\new_uspc\menu\macrodic.dcp";
var newPath = newEncodedFiles.Substring(0, dcpFile.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

This code returns:

```
C:\Users\wande\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Spira\Spira\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\Translated\master\new_uspc\menu\macro
```

I am trying to remove file extension to get:

```
C:\Users\wande\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Spira\Spira\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\Translated\master\new_uspc\menu\macrodic
```

Comment: You used `dcpFile.LastIndexOf('.')`. Did you mean to use `newEncodedFiles.LastIndexOf('.')` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working as expected for me in .net core 3.1 console application.

```
var newEncodedFiles = @"C:\Users\wande\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Spira\Spira\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\Translated\master\new_uspc\menu\macrodic.dcp";
var newPath = newEncodedFiles.Substring(0, newEncodedFiles.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

You need to use `newEncodedFiles`, not `dcpFile`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newEncodedFiles = @"C:\Users\wande\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2019\Spira\Spira\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\Translated\master\new_uspc\menu\macrodic.dcp";

var newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(newEncodedFiles ), System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newEncodedFiles ));
```